# How to fetch complex return value from (Oracle) stored function with Spring Data (JDBC)

Tags: oracle, spring-data, return-type, stored-functions, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to access a stored function from an oracle database package and fetch the complex return type.

Here are the required code snippets

```
function get_service_params_by_mac (p_mac_address in varchar2)
    return service_param_values_array;
```

```
CREATE TYPE SERVICE_PARAM_VALUES_ARRAY AS TABLE OF NAME_VALUE_PAIRS
```

```
create TYPE "NAME_VALUE_PAIRS" AS OBJECT (NAME VARCHAR2(255),VALUE VARCHAR2(240))
/
```

I can access the value from the result set like this in SQLDeveloper

```
DECLARE
    V_TEST SERVICE_PARAM_VALUES_ARRAY;
BEGIN
    V_TEST := SV_SVC_COLLECTION.GET_SERVICE_PARAMS_BY_MAC('00:11:22:33:44:55');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Size: ' || V_TEST.COUNT);
    FOR i IN 1..V_TEST.count
        LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_test(i).name || ' - ' || v_test(i).value);
        END LOOP;
END;
```

and the result is like:

```
Size: 34
A - 123
B - 456
C - 789
```

I tried to use `SimpleJdbcCall.executeFunction` but this does not really work

```
    public List<ServiceParameterDto> getServiceParamsByMac(@NotNull String macAddress) {
        var name = "GET_SERVICE_PARAMS_BY_MAC";
        var simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(getJdbcTemplate())
                .withSchemaName(getSchema())
                .withCatalogName(getPackageName())
                .withFunctionName(name).declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("P_MAC_ADDRESS", Types.VARCHAR)
                );

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(1);
        map.put("P_MAC_ADDRESS", macAddress);
        var dbResult = simpleJdbcCall.executeFunction(Arrays.class, map);

        var result = new ArrayList<ServiceParameterDto>();
        // ... work with db Result
        return result;
    }
```

The error message:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call ONSERVICE.SV_SVC_COLLECTION.GET_SERVICE_PARAMS_BY_MAC(?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Ungültiger Spaltentyp: 1111; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Ungültiger Spaltentyp: 1111

    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
```

Invalid column type 1111

Any ideas where I can start to look for complex return values?

Thanks alot in advance!

tried simplejdbccall and a sql query like the one from sqldeveloper to call the function

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/oraext5.htm#1039456
or a procedure with a SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter: will be seen a ResultSet in JDBC